# Post service is not updating value from Angular front, but it's working in postman

Tags: angular, web-services, angular-services, angular-httpclient

Here is the Request I do in Postman, it works fine, it just send a display value(string) "true"/"false" to enable or disable a tab, and then I check in the get request to get all tabs and see that it change the value of the tab.

[image]

The thing is in Angular, I'm sending the values and also getting a 200OK response no error but when I check at the postman get request I have no changes in the tab I disabled or enabled from the front

```
/**
   * get active tabs
   */
  public getAvailableTabs() {
    return (this.http.get<SiwaTabs[]>(`${ApiProvidersService.CurrentPath()}/Siwa/Settings/SiwaTabs`
    ).map(tabs => tabs.map(t => new SiwaTabs(
      t.id,
      t.title,
      t.route,
      t.UserID,
      t.display
    ))));
  }

  /**
   * set SiwaTabs
   * @param display
   * @param tabsID
   */
  public changeSiwaTabs(display: string, tabsID: number) {
    console.log(display, tabsID)
    return (this.http.post<any>(`${ApiProvidersService.CurrentPath()}/Siwa/Settings/changeSiwaTabs`, {
        display: display,
        tabsID: tabsID
      }
    ).map
    (result => result));
  }
```

Here is the ts file subscribing to the service

```
 /**
   * onInit
   * set initial theme
   * */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAvailableTabs();
    this.openSetting = "none";
    this.ReadOnlyStyleGuideNotes = true;
    this.Design = this.UserThemes.getTheme(this.User.activeUser.ThemeID);
    this.User.setTheme(this.User.activeUser.ThemeID);
    this.selectLang(this.User.activeUser.LanguageValue);
    this.selectedTabsID(this.Tabs);
    this.spinner = new Spinner();
    this.timedMessage = new TimedMessage();
    let id: number = 2
    let display: string = "true"
    this.User.changeSiwaTabs(display, id).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(display, id);
      console.log(res.status);
      if (res.status === true) {
        this.timedMessage.show(
          "Die Tabs wurden erfolgreich geändert",
          "alert-success",
          2000
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

This is the response from web browser:
[image]
[image]

What could I did wrong?

Comment: Should you send `boolean` value? Currently you send `string`

Comment: please avoid showing code in screenshots

Comment: I should send string, not boolean, the response of get the tabs service has display value as boolean, but this post service to change the display value it's sent as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was backend problems with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Answer (score 0):

I think in `changeSiwaTabs` function, `JSON.stringify` and `map` operator are useless.

It is a POST api so, the payload is a JSON object. You don't need to stringify that payload. And the `map` operator shouldn't be there because in `ngOnInit`, it's subscribed.

```
public changeSiwaTabs(display: string, tabsID: nubmer) {
    ...
    return this.http.post<any>(..., request);
```

Comment: It's not working either, I also get the same response that postman gave me like {
    "status": true
} but no changes in the tabs

Answer (score 0):

in get method you want boolean and you got string. am I right ?

Comment: in get method I have all the tabs tha each one has a display attribute boolean, but when I change the display value with post service I have ti send it like string, but this work fine, my problem is in angular

Comment: Can you share response of get request ? Get it from inspect element's network tab.

Comment: I updated the question with the response

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).